# Question in Convergence of a integral in the Heat Kernel and Dirac delta function.

Tags: heat-equation

In [Convergence of a integral - heat Kernel and dirac delta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557061/convergence-of-a-integral-heat-kernel-and-dirac-delta-function)

Why $$\lim_{t\to 0+}\int_{|x|>\delta}K_t(x)|\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)|\,dx=0?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $|\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)|$ is bounded uniformly, we can replace this by some constant $B$, and it suffices to show that $\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\int_{|x|>\delta}K_t(x)dx=0$. One way to do this is to do a change of variables to $u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}$. Then, by the change of variables formula,
$$
\int_{|x|>\delta}K_t(x)dx=\frac{1}{(4\pi)^{n/2}}\int_{|u|>\delta/\sqrt{t}}e^{-|u|^2/4} du
$$
Note that $\delta/\sqrt{t}$ goes to $\infty$, so the RHS goes to zero as $t\to 0^+$ because the integral of a Gaussian converges.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just found in the  , Measure and Integral text Wheeden and Zygmund that Theorem 9.5 implies that $\int_{|x|>\delta}K_t(x)\,dx\to 0$ when  $t\to 0$
Although I still don't know why $|\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)|$ is bounded uniformly in $|x|>\delta$.

Comment: I just saw why. Since $\varphi$ is a Schwartz function, it is bounded.